# action-to-action navigation in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

I'm migrating from weblogic (struts extension) to JSF2.

I wonder how can I navigate form one bean action to another bean action.
In weblogic, I would create and initialize form bean and I would return new Forward pointing to another action.

How can I do the same in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a normal practice in JSF. You would like to refactor the business logic out so that it can just be obtained/reused by multiple models (managed beans) independently.

Regardless, here's how you could do it: just inject the "other" action bean as managed property and invoke it in the current bean's action method:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{otherBean}")
private OtherBean otherBean;

public String doSomething() {
    return otherBean.doSomethingElse();
}
```